# Axios request to .net controller gives value of none

Tags: reactjs, asp.net, axios

I have this controller in .net

```
[HttpPost]
        [Route("check-code")]
        public ActionResult CheckDiscountCode(string code) 
        {
            string DiscountedCode = "MYCODE";

            if ( DiscountedCode == code.ToString().ToUpper() ) {
                return Json(true);
            } 
            else
            {
                return Json(false);
            }
        }
```

In React I have an axios request like this :

```
const response = await axios.post(process.env.REACT_APP_API_URL + '/check-code', discountCode)
```

Basicaly and I expect it to return if what the user has put in is valid or not. But when I breakpoint it everytime it says that the `code` is null and returns false no matter what I put in...

Answer (score 0):

Accordingly to [axios documentation](https://axios-http.com/docs/post_example), you need to specify the body of the request in the second argument of the post function, so make sure the discountCode passed in the second parameter is a object containing the field `code` and also make sure that in your controller you're expecting a body to read the code field from.

Answer (score 0):

If post as `axios.post(url,discountCode)`,
your payload will be like this:

```
{
    discountCode : ""
}
```

solution 1:

```
await axios.post(url, {code:discountCode})
```

solution 2: (change param name)

```
public ActionResult CheckDiscountCode(string discountCode)
```